# Как остановить и начать parallax эффект в определённый момент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Проблема с parallax эффектом.
Есть такой код:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(".sect_2").css("transform", "rotateX(" + st + "deg)");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #666;
  position: relative;
}

.sect_1 {
  background: green;
}

.sect_2 {
  width: 100%;
}

.sect_3 {
  background: red;
}

.text_1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15vw;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 20vw;
  margin-top: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<section class='sect_1'>
</section>

<section class='sect_2'>
  <div class='header_text_1 text_1'>
    Some text
  </div>
</section>"

<section class='sect_3'>
</section>
```

[Вот то, что у меня получилось](http://host2739.itelit.pro/php/zalic/try7.php)

Проблема в том, что я хочу чтобы при скролле он начинал крутится в определённый момент и чтобы он до parallax эффекта был в положении `rotateX(90deg)`, и закончил эффект при `rotateX(180deg)`. Если я пытаюсь так сделать, то ощущение, что этот блок поднимается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя много месяцев я случайно вспомнил, что задавал этот вопрос и подумал, что возможно кому-то нужен будет ответ на этот вопрос (ну если его, кто-то понял).

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
<title>Document</title>
<style>
body{
    margin:0;
}
section{
    height:100vh;
    background-color: #666; 
    position: relative;
}
.sect_1{
    background:green;
}
.sect_2{
    width:100%;
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
.sect_3{
    background:red;
}
.text_1{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 15vw;
    display: inline-block;
    width:240px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20vw;
    margin-top: 20vw;
}   
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?
    echo "<section class='sect_1'>";
    echo "</section>";

    echo "<section class='sect_2'>";
    echo "<div class='header_text_1 text_1'>";
    echo "Some text";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</section>"; 

    echo "<section class='sect_3'>";
    echo "</section>";
?>
<script src="wow-animation/wow.min.js"></script>
<script>
    new WOW().init();
</script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>     
</body>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(st > 180){
        $(".sect_2").css("transform", "rotateX(180deg)");
    }
    // 90 потому что потом после того как st станет 90, .sect_2 начнёт rotateX с значения 90
    else if(st > 90) {
        $(".sect_2").css("transform", "rotateX(" + st +"deg)");
    }else {
        $(".sect_2").css("transform", "rotateX(90deg)");
    }

});
</script>
```